# Python process started by IIS stops running after awhile

Tags: php, python, iis-8, windows-server-2016

I wrote a `python` script which is collecting links from a given web page. You can find a code snippet below. (but I think it is not a coding issue).

When I execute the script in command line (with administrator rights) everything works as expected, but when I run the script from `PHP` it just stops running after ~30 minutes without any Exception. For me it looks like, that Windows Server 2016 is killing the `python` process after a certain time (process is started by IIS User without admin rights).

Any ideas how to tell Windows/IIS not to kill the `python` process?

This is how I call the script from `PHP`:

```
$command = 'C:\\Python36\\python.exe C:\\Scripts\\myscript.py ';
pclose(popen("start /B ".$command, "w"));
```

I tried both `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`. The script is starting normally, but stops after about 30 minutes.

```
def getAllLinksOnCurrentPage():
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    f = elem.get_attribute("href")
    if testurl in f:
        if f not in linkcollector:
            linkcollector.append(f)


try:
    driver.get(testurl)

    for currentpage in linkcollector:
        driver.get(currentpage)
        getAllLinksOnCurrentPage()


    #Write all URLs to Logfile
    with open('C:\Scripts\Logfiles\\Logfile.txt', "a") as file:
        for currentpage in linkcollector:
            file.write("\n%s" %currentpage)

except Exception as e:
    #Catch Unknown Exception
    with open('C:\Scripts\Logfiles\\'+str(testrun)+'_Logfile.txt', "a") as file:
        file.write("\n Unknown Exception: " %str(e))
```

Every input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Solution found by myself:

IIS -> select server -> Default App Pool -> Advanced Settings -> set 0 to "Idle time out" and "regular time interval"

Comment: This does not work even after setting the pool to always running mode and the website as preload enabled. After approx 5 minutes if no request comes, the python process dies.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to [max-execution-time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) - The maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated.

You can changed this property by editing php.ini or by calling [set-time-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: max-execution-time is not supported in newer versions of PHP